# Accessing c# desktop application remotely

Tags: c#, inventory

I want to a build an inventory application on c#.
The main feature in this context is, allowing ADMIN to access the application from anywhere through internet.

The case which comes to my mind are :
 1. building an extension or Child app which can perform such task (by fetching data from parent)
 2. creating a client server application (which not at all sounds convincing)

On a second thought --

How about dividing the app in two components - "ADMIN and MAIN" Application.
The ADMIN component can connect to the MAIN application through internet and fetch the data, whatsoever required. So that ADMIN specific functionality can be implemented in this component.

How can i implement this idea.
Please suggest me, the best way to do so.
Feel free to add any other solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An inventory app must use a .db., just create a website.

Comment: Not possible.
The application will go online just to provide access to admin.
Internet is not required for any other purposes apart from this.
So a desktop app and another admin viewer component will be a good idea according to me

Comment: I'm not talking about creating a full public website. I'm talking about creating a site that the admin could gain access to. You are clearly opening up access for admin anyway.